# Why does the burndown chart include weekends and nights?

Tags: scrum, agile, burn-charts

Currently my team's burndown charts includes weekends and nights, I feel like this harms the velocity by misrepresenting it, however, I cannot explain this very well.

This is what is going on in my head...

In my team `Velocity = Number of Story Points Completed / Sprint` and `Sprint = 2 Weeks`

[image]

So as an example, in the above image, the commit is 50 story points, while the team was only able to deliver `50 - 10 = 40` story points this sprint, so the team's velocity is 40 story points.

**Removing Weekends**

[image]

Currently the target burndown chart generate by JIRA (grey) at the start of the sprint includes the weekends, I feel like it should not include the weekends (blue). What are the benefits of including the weekends? What are the downsides of removing the weekends? **Does including the weekends harm velocity?**

**Removing Nights**

[image]

Because we track nights, everyday we go above the target line (grey) and it looks like we are under-delivering. What are the benefits of including the nights? What are the downsides of removing the nights? **Does including the weekends harm nights?**

---

What also came to me while writing this, is that during planning we say that each developer will do 8 hours of work per day, however, we track 24 hours of work per day.

Comment: IIRC JIRA has a checkbox to hide/show weekends/holidays.

Comment: Yes, but, why include them in the first place?

Comment: Remember the concept of "week" [varies according to the country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workweek_and_weekend#Muslim_countries).

Comment: @TiagoCardoso, interesting info, but how can I use it to help answer my question(s)? What were you trying to say with this?

Comment: I'm answering the "*why include them (weekends) in the first place?*" question. Consider multi located teams - the work burned on my "weekends" (where "they" work) should be considered. Right?

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right, in my case, we don't have anyone remote (in a different time zone), so....

Answer (score 6):

This question is worth hitting from a few angles:

**The Direct Answer**

First, to your question, I've never been in a team that found value in showing days on the burndown chart they weren't working. Feel free to hide those days, it won't hurt anything.

As to why Jira puts it in at all, the answer would simply be that some people work irregular weeks. Easier to include it and let people hide them, than to try to code a special case for teams that work irregular weeks.

**Velocity**

Velocity is not calculated daily, but by the sprint, so this has no effect on measurements.

**Use of Burndown Charts**

More importantly, if you feel like you are underdelivering because of the horizontal lines, you are reading way too granualarly into this tool. The purpose of a burndown chart is to allow the team and others around them to see the trend of work through the sprint at a glance. Your brain will learn to account for nights or weekends having an odd bump within a day or two.

The burndown chart just shows you one interesting trend in a lot of data. It should never be managed to.

**Other Tools**

These charts are super easy to draw. If you'd like a different visualization of this chart, taskboards, or any other visualizations, I'd highly recommend using other tools too. The 30 seconds per day that JIRA saves you isn't particularly critical, especially if you're unhappy with how JIRA is visualizing it. Just create a chart that works better. Plus, you can have fun with it then. I had a team whose burndown chart was modeled after the game Lemmings and if they reached the bottom they saved the Lemmings. So much more interesting than a line on JIRA.

Comment: Every morning / Monday we open the burndown chart to check our "progress" and every morning / Monday our burndown line is above the target burndown line, so the team makes a conclusion that we are under-delivering, that is why I was wondering why we are tracking time during which no one is working...

Comment: @aflaflavich Then your team is misusing the metric. Even if you include non-work days, the goal is a trend that will approach zero at the end of a Sprint, and *not* just a smooth line.